# GLSL texture layout

Tags: opengl, glsl, textures

How does the layout of the matrix (row-major vs column-major) affect the GLSL texture that it creates? Does the access to that texture changes in the shader? In case of the column-major matrix should I first change the matrix to row-major and then upload it to GPU as a texture?

Comment: @Rabbid76 I'm uploading this matrix as a texture and then I will access it in the shader, and I think the accessing part is kind of mixed up. I don't know when the texture is created how the memory access will be like

Comment: @user3178756: Show us some code so that we can understand what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [The OpenGL Shading Language 4.6, 5.4.2 Vector and Matrix Constructors, page 101](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.pdf):

> To initialize a matrix by specifying vectors or scalars, the components are assigned to the matrix elements in **column-major order**.
>
> ```
> mat4(float, float, float, float,  // first column
>      float, float, float, float,  // second column
>      float, float, float, float,  // third column
>      float, float, float, float); // fourth column
> ```

This means if you store the matrices (`mat4`) in the lines of a 2 dimensional 4*N, RGBA texture, like this:

```
         0           1           2           3
mat4 m0  m0[0].xyzw  m0[1].xyzw  m0[2].xyzw  m0[3].xyzw
mat4 m1  m1[0].xyzw  m1[1].xyzw  m1[2].xyzw  m1[3].xyzw
mat4 m2  m2[0].xyzw  m2[1].xyzw  m2[2].xyzw  m2[3].xyzw
mat4 m3  .....
```

```
mat4 matArray[N]; // possibly std::vector<glm::mat4>( N );

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA32F, 4, N, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, matArray);
```

then you can read the matrices from the texture in the shader like this:

```
uniform sampler2D matSampler; 

void main()
{
    mat4 m0 = mat4(
        texelFetch( matSampler, ivec(0, 0), 0),
        texelFetch( matSampler, ivec(1, 0), 0),
        texelFetch( matSampler, ivec(2, 0), 0),
        texelFetch( matSampler, ivec(3, 0), 0) );

    mat4 m1 = mat4(
        texelFetch( matSampler, ivec(0, 1), 0),
        texelFetch( matSampler, ivec(1, 1), 0),
        texelFetch( matSampler, ivec(2, 1), 0),
        texelFetch( matSampler, ivec(3, 1), 0) );

   .....      
}
```